# access mysql in host from guest virtualbox

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, virtualbox

This is my scenario,

I have a Ubuntu 12.10 host and a win 7 guest installed in the virtual box. The Network is configured to be NAT in the virtual box. I have a mysql sever installed in the Ubuntu with “bind_address” in my.cnf is commented out.

How can I access this mysql server from the windows 7 guest? I did some search in Google and came accross with this [Host-Only Networking With VirtualBox](http://christophermaier.name/blog/2010/09/01/host-only-networking-with-virtualbox) but I cant get it work as I don't have statics IP with my internet vendor and my network knowledge is very bad. All I know is that I have DHCP enabled Internet connection. So if i do any IP's in the network settings I don't have Internet.

I know that there are plenty of solutions on the other way around (access the guest server from the host) but still cant figure it out.

So any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your external IP being static or not has no bearing to accessing a virtualized server on your LAN.
Set VirtualBox to bridge mode.

Simply determine your computer's DHCP-selected internal IP (usually `192.168.1.SOMETHING`) and replace the last number with another that is less than 250. For example, if your computer was `192.168.1.6`, `192.168.1.70` would work fine on the VM (pick a high number to void conflicts).

Set it by using the control panel->adapter settings. Reboot  the VM. Connect to MySQL at 192.168.1.70(or the address you picked earlier).

Note: If your computer's address is in a different subnet (192.168.0.XXX, 10.XX.XX.XX, etc) change the last number and keep the first numbers the same as on the host.

Comment: what about the VM network? Do i have to change it to something else from NAT? I have the internet to host but nothing in the guest...

Comment: I explained in my post, "Set VirtualBox to bridge mode."

Comment: Have you followed the entire set of instructions, including editing the VM guest's configuration files?

Comment: Yes.. I did not had Ip on the host so i made it to 192.168.1.70 and then the VM to 192.168.1.80. So the mysql server is in 192.168.1.70 and when i try to ping it from VM it says "destination host unreachable". and i have a wireless connection so i used wlan0 insted eth0

Comment: What is the ORIGINAL IP your host had? it has to be in the same subnet as it was originally.

Comment: It did not had any IP. It was set to Automatic (DHCP) and the host is ubuntu and guest is win 7.

Comment: As I said, you need to turn DHCP off on the guest and pick an IP in the same subnet as the IP the host gets over DHCP. So if the host got A.B.C.63, the guest would need the same A, B, and C, and a different last digit.

Comment: ok i used ifconfig and the result is ' 
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          and i set the VM on 192.168.1.80 and the same mask...

Comment: Um? That's blank. This shouldn't be as hard as you're making it, unless there's some sort of odd configuration with your router. Then give the guest 192.168.1.70, set it to bridged networking(make sure you bridge to the correct adapter), reboot the guest, and connect from the host.

Comment: Ok I removed the IP in the host and set it to DHCP and Now I can ping to the host but the issue is mysql server gives this error "Host '192.168.1.80' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server" i think i have to enable remote connection to mysql server

Comment: *sigh* You need to set the permissions for the SQL user you are connecting from. It has to be `username@%`, not `username@localhost`.

Comment: Thanks and I will look in to that. At-least I can connect to the host from guest. Thanks Again..

Comment: This works if I bridge as described.  however, I have a host-only network set up as well.  I should be able to connect using the IP of the host machgine on the host-only network, but that doesn't work.  Any ideas?