# Database replication using virtual box

Tags: mysql, linux, database, connection, virtual-machine

I want to set up MySQL replication using 2 machines: 1 machine is my Windows 8 - computer and the other is a Ubuntu Virtual Machine using VirtualBox!

I want to use windows as the master and the linux as the slave. I have set up everything for the master and the slave (server-id, CHANGE MASTER TO statement, new user created on the master for the slave, ...)

Still, when I execute the query "SHOW SLAVE STATUS;" Linux keeps on saying "connecting to master".

The database on the master runs on the localhost (127.0.0.1:3306). I use a host-only adapter to connect the windows machine to the virtual machine. The IP of the host only adapter is 192.168.50.106 and the IP of the linux machine is 192.168.50.151.

Why I can't I seem to connect to my localhost?

Comment: The answer to this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324611/access-mysql-in-host-from-guest-virtualbox